# How can I stop Excel from rapidly refreshing/flickering while data is being loaded from external sources?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts, external-data

I have an Excel spreadsheet with several charts on the same worksheet. Each chart's data comes from a different table. Each table's data is pulled from an Access database, and the connections for each table are set to refresh upon opening the workbook, when opening the workbook all of the charts will flash (between visible and not visible) several times very rapidly. Is there any way to prevent this flashing while the data is being updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck/turn-off `Enable background refresh` on all of the Workbook Connections.

Comment: This seems to have resolved the issue for me. The `Refresh data when opening the file` option still works, but now the screen does not flash at all when opening the workbook. I turned the `Enable background refresh` option back on for one of the connections and the flashing started again. Turned it back off for that connection and the workbook no longer flashes. So, the flashing seems to have something to do with the `Enable background refresh` option.

Comment: Question: Doesn't `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` help you? I'm curious

Comment: I did not did try `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. I figured out turning off the `Enable background refresh` option before @STTR posted a solution, and was happy enough with it. I do intend to try to out his answer at some point though.

Comment: @nixda, I forgot to come back comment that `Application.ScreenUpdating` was a working solution. I feel like my answer of unchecking `Enable background refresh` is a better answer though because it does not require a macro-enabled workbook, or knowledge of VBA

Answer (score 4):

```
Public Sub StroboscopeOff()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub

Public Sub StroboscopeOn()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Use:

```
StroboscopeOff()

.. Update Data    

StroboscopeOn()
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, this was a working solution, even just changing `Application.ScreenUpdating` was enough. I feel like my answer of unchecking `Enable background refresh` is a better answer though because it does not require a macro-enabled workbook, or knowledge of VBA.